# Word VBA - Get Value From Drop-Down List Content Control to Color Cell In Table

Tags: microsoft-word, vba

Trying to color a cell based on drop-down CC. Here is what I got - not working getting "require object" error. I have added the drop down CC in the document and named and tagged it dropdown1.

I guess I am not initiating the object correctly or the doc.ContentControls("dropwdown1").Result reference does not work. Could you help me?

Also is there a way in VBA to see all the CC objects already in the document and see their names/tags so I know how to reference them?

```
Private Sub color(ByVal ContentControl As ContentControl, Cancel As Boolean)
Dim i As Long
 Dim tbl As Table, rw As Row, v1
    Set tbl = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
    
With ContentControl
  If .Title = "dropdown1" Then
  For i = 1 To .DropdownListEntries.Count
    If .DropdownListEntries(i).Text = "HIGH" Then
            rw.Cells(1).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(0, 250, 0)
            Else
            rw.Cells(1).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(250, 250, 250)
      Exit For
    End If
  Next
  End If
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Try to look here: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/67356779](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67356779), also `ActiveDocument.ContentControls` collection contains all `ContentControl` objects (which have their `.Title` property)

Comment: Mh - I looked at that before, thank you. I edited my example - I am still having trouble getting it to work. Also I realized that I would only need to color one specific cell in a table based on the input of a specific Drop-Down - each cell in a table will be colored based on a different dropdown.

Comment: it may be that `ByVal ContentControl As ContentControl` is giving you issues, as the variable name is the same as the Type/Object declaration. I *think* this is legal, but then you need to specifically identify the object. Docs use `Left` as an example, and say that to use the *string function* `Left` in a scope where `Left` is a variable, then the function needs to be referenced as `VBA.Left` ( https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/visual-basic-naming-rules )

Comment: I took that directly from, the above post - seems to be working there.